# Android - OAuth app with popupWindow

Tags: android, oauth, popupwindow

I'm trying to make an app with a login for my site. The server side login stuff is done, so now I'm just creating the app for it.
The plan is to have a login button. When the login button is pressed, a `popupWindow` is invoked and the layout is set to a `webView` pointing to my URL. I have this part working. The `popupWindow` appears, and I can see my login box, so the connection is there.

However, the screen becomes unresponsive. If I click on the username field to try some text entry, nothing happens. The back button also doesnt work. I have to press the home button to get out of it.

Also, I have code where it loads the built in browser, and obviously I can login and that works perfect, but it never returns to my app, hence why I've opted for the `popupWindow`.

Can someone share some tips for how to do this properly, or link me to some sample code? Basically any code with a `popupWindow` being used to login to a website would be perfect!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OAuth and REST in Android](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/05/25/oauth-and-rest-in-android-part-1/), nice guide for creating OAuth requests with intents.

Comment: Thanks. That works for loading the browser and sending the Intent back. I suppose I'll have to give up on using a `popupWindow` then.

Comment: Use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" for the browser Activity and it will show as a popup dialog.

Comment: hmm, thats a good idea! But I'm using `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authURL)));` to launch the browser, so it doesnt have its own activity that I can set a theme on.  Can I create a new activity with a `webView` embedded in it, then set the theme, and then call `startActivity` on it? OR could I maybe just create a new `<intent filter>` in the `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: @eoinzy - just create an intent filter in your manifest, and give a callback URL like "myappcallback://myapcallback"